# How to save hyperlink Dynamically to a sharepoint calendar list?

Tags: sharepoint, list

I have a calendar list called "learning Calendar" and it has the following fields.
**Location,Start Time,Start Time,Employee Name,Manage Name,Program Name,Status,HyperLink.**
I am able to add the data into it sucessfully. 
But i would like to save current URl into HyperLink field in the list dynamically. How can i achive this? Here is the saved Date

Location     - AAA
Start Time   -2/14/2012  7:00:00 PM
Start Time   -2/14/2012  8:00:00 PM
Employee Name-BBBB
Manage Name  -CCCC
Program Name -DDDD
Status       -Approved

HyperLink    - ? how do i save dynamically URl here ? (Statically i am able to add)

Please Help.